# Is it possible to achieve open NAT (Type 1) on my PS4?

Tags: networking, home-networking, nat, ps4

I have the Huawei B5142 device from my carrier. This device is the source of internet connection to my home's router. My PS4 is wirelessly connected directly to the Huawei device, bypassing my router. The Huawei device has a public IP address such as 196.210.3.4, and an internal address such as 10.15.3.11, my PS4 has a traditional 192.168.1.50 address which is static.

I should note that my ISP currently uses NAT444 / LSN (Large Scale NAT), however the public and router internal addresses (196.210.3.4 and 10.15.3.11) are static allocations from my ISP's network.

I have de-activated the router's built-in firewall and DMZ'd my PS4's internal address (192.168.1.50), yet I still get a moderate (Type 2) NAT result.

Is there something else I can try or is an open NAT type even possible behind CGN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Is there something else I can try or is an open NAT type even possible behind CGN?
```

Nope, CGN makes it impossible

The alternative is to use a VPN provider that allows you to use UPnP and gives a dedicated IP. Then you need to connect the Huawei to it to force the PS4 over it. This will fix NAT but will add latency which in most cases will be worse.